# Switching between outputs using irfz44n mosfet

Tags: mosfet, switching, pulldown, single-supply-op-amp

[image]

In the circuit shown, the input voltage to the op-amp ua741 is 1V and the output will be 5.7V, which switches the bottom left irfz44n mosfet on and the off voltage irfz44n mosfet off. So i would expect the voltage from the first voltage divider [0.8*12= 9.6- 0.7= 8.9 Volts] which is 8.9V to appear at the output (at the junction where sources of both mosfets and the 10kohm pull down resistor meet). However i get 2.13 volts with minute fluctuations. Why is this happening? How do i fix this. Threshold voltage of irfz44n is 4V.

Comment: "*Switching between outputs using irfz44n mosfet*", is this another way of saying "*I'm trying to make a multiplexer(mux) using irfz44n*"?

Comment: Yes.However, i would like to solve the problem in this circuit itself. I know there are simpler ways.

Comment: Slightly off topic but is this mux supposed to have a lot of current going through it, like routing power, or is it supposed to just do math, such as passing signals, like a typical mux.

Comment: Should just be able to select the respective signal sources.

Comment: Okay, so there should be a total of three inputs and one output, two inputs *A*, *B* and one input *S* that decides which of *A* and *B* that should go to output *Y* I guess, where are these 4 points in your schematic?

Comment: Input S is at the non-inverting terminal of op-amp(1volt). Inputs A and B are the outputs of the two 1kohm potentiometers (on voltage and off voltage). Output Y is the wire joining the sources of the two MOSFETs below.

Comment: Is it possible that the common-mode voltage range of your grounded V- 741 op amp is causing problems? See this post: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/142293/op-amps-negative-power-supply-to-ground.

Comment: In other words, 1V at the NI input doesn't produce the gain you expect and the output is less than the voltage needed to turn the mosfet on fully.  The mosfet DS resistance is higher and the voltage drop causes a lower voltage at the top of R5.

Comment: And if I'm reading voltage from the output(wire joining the source terminals of the two MOSFETs at the bottom) using analog pin of arduino, I should connect ground of arduino to 12V power supply Vp ground, right? I'm reading via serial communication to my pc.

Comment: I assume your grounds are all connected together.  That's the way it looks in your schematic. So, the grounded end of R5 is connected to Vp and Vpn.  I would simply change the op amp to one that will allow you get closer to the negative rail. The 741 is an old op amp that works best with a dual (+ and -) supply (plenty of commentary about that on this site).